# How to rename all variables according to rule set with AST

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

Is there a tool that is capable of iterating over all variables and function arguments in a Python file and replace them according to a style rule? For example, given a function in `myModule.py`

```
def myFunc(Variable):
    Tmp = sin(Variable)
    return Tmp * 2
```

Is there a tool that could be called in a manner like the following

`> tool myModule.py --variable-begin-with-lowercase`

to produce the result below?

```
def myFunc(variable):
    tmp = sin(variable)
    return tmp * 2
```

I suppose, that the tool should warn about renamings that interfere with existing variables.

Comment: `rope` might be able to help you: https://github.com/python-rope/rope

Comment: Still, how would I be able to get my variables PEP8 compliant, without manually going through each function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`ast.NodeTransformer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.NodeTransformer):

```
import ast

class toLower(ast.NodeTransformer):
    def visit_arg(self, node):
        return ast.arg(**{**node.__dict__, 'arg':node.arg.lower()})

    def visit_Name(self, node):
        return ast.Name(**{**node.__dict__, 'id':node.id.lower()})

code = """
def myFunc(Variable):
    Tmp = sin(Variable)
    return Tmp * 2
"""
new_code = ast.unparse(toLower().visit(ast.parse(code)))
print(new_code)
```

Output:

```
def myFunc(variable):
    tmp = sin(variable)
    return tmp * 2
```

Comment: It would be nice to check whether the rename causes a name clash.

Comment: @Frank I put together [a proof-of-concept](https://gist.github.com/wjandrea/ec0852535e3a03d2167a9d66602b77ae) for that.